# How to find forground application Unique ID/Name in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have problem in finding the current opened application name.
I used ApplicationManager class for getting the visible applications. 
The application descriptors are showing the same name for all these apps Email,Messaging,Sms,call log. 
They are displaying  "net_rim_bb_messaging_app" for all the above apps.

I need to find a unique identifier/name for these applications(Email,messaging,sms,calllog) when they are opened.
I tried this for the past 3 days and can't find a solution.
Can you please let me know a solution for this?

```
ApplicationDescriptor [] appDis = manager.getVisibleApplications();
int currentForgroundAppID = manager.getForegroundProcessId();

for(int i=0;i<appIDs.length;i++)
{
    if(appDis[i].getModuleName().equals("net_rim_bb_messaging_app"))
    {
        //print Messaging app in foreground...
    }
}
```

the case with in the for loop above is true for every app in this list.

1. Email,
2. Text message
3. Call log...

But, I need to find a unique way to find the application that was opened.

Thanks In Adv,

Satish.k

Comment: You must contact RIM.
and ask them to add another function to find this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code can display current foregroundApplication name

```
ApplicationDescriptor[] mAppDes;
    ApplicationManager appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
                    appMan.getForegroundProcessId();

                    mAppDes = appMan.getVisibleApplications(); 
                           for (int i = 0; i < mAppDes.length; i++) {
                              boolean isFG = appMan.getProcessId(mAppDes[i]) == appMan.getForegroundProcessId();
                                if(isFG)
                                {
                                   System.out.println("This is your Foteground application Name"+mAppDes[i].getName());
                                  }else{
                                      System.out.println("This is your Background application Name"+mAppDes[i].getName());
                                  }
                            }
```